# Split the column in two parts using sql : Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a column named File size which contains the data in the format attached in the image :
[image]

and so on . I need to strip the integer part of file size and create a separate column for that. What is the simplest way to do it using sql query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select to_number(substr(filesize, 1, instr(filesize, ' ') - 1)) from your_table;
```

will strip the space after the integer and the KB from each string.

Please clarify if you need help with creating a column or populating it with the result from this select statement.

**Edit**:  If you need to add a column:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD size_in_kb NUMBER;
```

Then, to update the new column with the integers extracted from `filesize`:

```
update your_table set size_in_kb = 
                                  to_number(substr(filesize, 1, instr(filesize, ' ') - 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I knew it was not that difficult and No I wasn't looking to create a new column in Table , just wanted to have this column as an output of query to run some analysis on it.